# View rails record details in bootstrap modal on row click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time now and looked through several posts as well, however I cannot achieve exactly what I want for my Rails application. Essentially, I want to be able to click on a table row on my page and have a modal pop up which displays all the information for that specific record. Here are the scenarios which I have thought of/attempted partially:

1. Set the data-link attribute in table row with some JS as follows

HTML:

`<tr data-link="<%= kid_path %>">
   ...
</tr>`

JS:

`$("tr[data-link]").dblclick(function() {
      window.location = $(this).data("link")
 })`

This worked fine to open the show path page generated by the scaffold, but I was not able to modify it to work with a modal and have the same data for the kid in the modal.

2. Use data-id and JavaScript to load onto the modal

HTML:

`<tr data-id="<%= kid.id %>">
   ...
</tr>`

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('#showModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: "static",
        show: false,

     }).on('show', function () {

    });

 $(".table-striped").find('tr[data-id]').on('click', function () {
    debugger;

       $('#showDetails').html($('<p>' + 'Kid ID: ' + $(this).data('id') + '<%= Kid.find(30).first_name %>' + '</p>'));
       $('#showModal').modal('show');
   });
});
```

In this approach I am able to load the modal on row click and am able to access the Kid ID, however I cannot move further to access other attributes of the record. For example, I want to set @Kid = kid.find(id) using JS where id would be the extracted ID from the row. And then, I want to be able to write the generic modal template which displays other elements (ex. kid.first_name, kid.last_name, etc).

I am totally stuck and cannot find any approach that helps to accomplish my goal. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ajax call record attributes because the line `Kid.find(30).first_name` doesn't exist at the time page loaded.

Try this:

**KidsController**

```
def show
  kid = Kid.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { // Usually show.html.erb }
    format.json do
      # Return kid as json object
      result = {
        first_name: kid.first_name,
        last_name: kid.last_name
      }
      # If you want to return the whole kid record attributes in json: result = kid.attributes.to_json 
      render json: result
    end
  end
end
```

Try `/kid/[:id].json` to verify that you are not getting `UnknownFormat` error.

JS

```
$(".table-striped").find('tr[data-id]').on('click', function () {
  var kid_id = $(this).data('id');
  $.getJSON("/kid/" + kid_id, function(data) {
    // Render the modal body here
    // first_name = data.first_name, last_name = data.last_name etc
    $('#showDetails').html($('<p>'+ data.first_name + '</p>'));
    $('#showModal').modal('show');
  });
})
```

If you have setup correct route for `Kid` model then these are what you needed.

**UPDATED**: I made a typo in the `result` hash. FIXED

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try this. Also, how will I output the first_name in the modal?

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer with better explanation, hope that helps. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: So I tweaked it a little to get rid of errors, but when I click on the row nothing happens, inspect element showed this error on click "GET http://localhost:3000/kids/30 500 (Internal Server Error)" and in the console it shows "NameError (undefined local variable or method 'first_name' for #<KidsController:0x0000000ad5c208>):
  app/controllers/kids_controller.rb:20:in 'block (2 levels) in show'
  app/controllers/kids_controller.rb:15:in 'show". Any ideas? I changed the following: format.html {redirect_to root_path} in the controller.

Comment: hiya, I updated my answer again. I made a syntactic error accidentally. Can you try  localhost:3000/kids/30.json to see if it works?

Comment: localhost:3000/kids/30.json works and the row click also works to show the name in modal, thank you! After 3 weeks of searching and trying your solution has finally solved my problem

Comment: sweet, glad it helps you :)

Comment: hey any idea how I could extend this idea to edit as well in a modal ?

Comment: `edit` and `show` are almost identical in this case, how would you see the difference?

Comment: the submit button would update the record in the edit case, however in this case i beleive we are just pulling json text data and outputting it ...

Comment: correct, with `edit` action, you want to output form into modal body instead ie `html("<%= render form %>)`, pretty standard way.

Comment: so I guess I would have to design the actual modal body in the 'form' file if i understand correctly?