# Rails edit record in a modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have successfully been able to view records in my Rails app in a modal using the following solution [View rails record details in bootstrap modal on row click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38289100/view-rails-record-details-in-bootstrap-modal-on-row-click) however now I want to edit the same record in a similar looking modal. I have been through several posts however none of the approaches seem to work or execute properly. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: So, you're trying to now load the edit template inside a modal. I would suggest trying to extend the ajax technique you learned from the linked question. It's pretty straight forward. Think.

Comment: You might want to look at the following guide. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: @manu29.d in the linked question it uses a JSON call to get all the data in text format, how would I be able to extend that to the edit function ?